# copy constructor clarification needed

Tags: java, copy-constructor

```
public class CopyConstructorEx 
{
    String web, webb;

    CopyConstructorEx(String w){ 
        web = w;       }         

    CopyConstructorEx(CopyConstructorEx je){    
            webb = je.web;         }  

    void disp(){        
         System.out.println("Website: "+web);      }        

    public static void main(String args[]){

        CopyConstructorEx obj1 = new CopyConstructorEx("BeginnersBook");                

        CopyConstructorEx obj2 = new CopyConstructorEx(obj1);           

        obj1.disp();
        obj2.disp();       
   }      
}
```

**output:**

> Website: BeginnersBook
>
> Website: null

Can anyone explain why second output is null?

Comment: Please edit the question and format the code properly (select code, click on the code button on toolbar) and also tag the language you’re using. And if this is c++ then it cannot be null.

Comment: `obj1` is initialized using the first constructor. The field `web` gets the value `"BeginnersBook"`. `obj2` is initialized by the second constructor which sets the field `webb` to the value of `je.web`: `"BeginnersBook"`. Thus you have following states:  `obj1.web.equals("BeginnersBook")` / `obj1.webb == null` and  `obj2.web == null` / `obj2.webb.equals("BeginnersBook")`. The method `disp` prints the value of the field `web`.

Answer (score 2):

`web` being a `string` type variable is null by default. In your copy constructor, you aren't assigning anything to it, so there's no reason for it to change.